# Linear zoom function 2D

Tags: math, canvas, zooming

I have a canvas and a scale value. The maximum scale is 1, the minimum scale value is something like 0.1 or above.
Let’s say we have discrete time units. I’m looking for a function that zooms linear over an time interval `I` (lets say 100 time units), from a start zoom `s` to an end zoom `e`. Let `0 >= i < I` be the current interval.

Example: Zoom from 0.2 to 1.0 in 100 time units.

Obviously `zoom(i) = (e-s)/I * i` does not produce a linear zoom. Because a step from 0.2 to 0.4 doubles the zoom, while the same amount from 0.8 to 1.0 only increases the zoom by 25%.

I was thinking that this function needs something logarithmic to base 2, but I’m stuck finding the right function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To provide constant ratio with constant argument difference, you need exponential function (it is possible to use any base,  `e, 2, 10` and so on with corresponding logarithms)

```
F(x) = A * Exp(B * x)
```

To get coefficients A and B for given border conditions (argument x0 corresponds to function value F0):

```
F0 = A * Exp(B * x0)
F1 = A * Exp(B * x1)
```

divide the second equation by the first:

```
Exp(B * (x1 -x0) = F1 / F0
B * (x1 -x0) = ln(F1 / F0)
```

so

```
B = ln(F1 / F0) / (x1 - x0)
```

and

```
A = F0 * Exp(-B * x0)
```

For your example

```
x0=0, x1=100
zoom0 = 0.2, zoom1=1
B = ln(5) / 100 = 0.0161
A = 0.2 * Exp(0) = 0.2
zoom(i) = 0.2 * Exp(0.0161 * i)

zoom(0) = 0.2
zoom(50) = 0.447
zoom(100) = 1

note that 
zoom(50) / zoom(0) = zoom(100) / zoom(50)
```

Comment: Im unfamiliar with the syntax of  `Exp` can you tell me what is the base and what the exponent
because `0.2* 50^0.0161` (zoom 50 in the example) is 0.213

Comment: never mind. I just found out that it's the exponential function to the base e.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not a logarithm but [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root). You requirements is effectively following: you want to find such sequence `A[i]` that

1. `A[0]` = 0.1
2. `A[N]` = 1
3. `A[i+1]`/`A[i]` = `k`, where `k`is some constant

The solution for this is obviously

```
A[i] = 0.1 * k^i
```

and so `k` should be

```
k^N = 1/0.1 = 10
```

or

```
k = root(10, N) = 10^(1/N)
```

For practical reasons it might be better to use N which is power of 2 so you can calculate some intermediate results by multiplying by a lesser root to have less 
rounding error accumulated. What I means is that

```
a[N/2] = sqrt(0.1) = 0.1 * sqrt(1/0.1)
a[N/4] = 0.1 * root(1/0.1, 4)
a[3*N/4] = a[N/2] * root(1/0.1, 4)
```

It also might make sense to change starting value of `0.1` to something that is itself some power for example `1/9` or `1/16`

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I decided to use @mbo s solution, because I found the formula simpler to understand.